# how to correctly send ajax request for a javascript response block

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am using ajax call to a remote server which is supposed to return a javascript block in response . My ajax call is something like :

```
    var m3_u = (location.protocol=='https:'?'https://ads.admarvel.com/fam/javascriptGetAd.php':'http://ads.admarvel.com/fam/javascriptGetAd.php');
    var m3_r = Math.floor(Math.random()*99999999999);
    var queryString = '?partner_id='+partnerId;
queryString += '&site_id='+siteId;
queryString += '&target_params=' + targetparams_str;
queryString += '&version=1.5';
queryString += '&language=javascript';
queryString += '&format=wap';
queryString += '&cb='+m3_r;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
                {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                alert(xmlhttp);

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
                {
                    alert(xmlhttp.readyState);
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4)
                    {
                        alert("response "+xmlhttp.responseXML);
                        console.log(xmlhttp.responseXML);
                        //document.getElementById('ad').innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                        //document.write("<scr"+"ipt type='text/javascript'>");
                        //document.write(xmlhttp.responseText); 
                        //document.write("<\/scr"+"ipt>");
                    }
                }

                xmlhttp.open("GET",m3_u+queryString,false);

                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','text/javascript');
                xmlhttp.send();
```

But the response that I am getting is *null* .
When I hit the url in the broser , it properly returns me a javascript code block .

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Is this a same-domain ajax call?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're setting `Content-Type` as a request header if you're using GET.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do Cross site XMLHTTPRequest.

You have to handle Cross Site XMLHttpRequest differently. If you implement in Java you may follow below URL

http://mytechbites.blogspot.com/2009/07/cross-domain-xmlhttprequest-calls.html

Otherwise use jQuery.ajax.

Comment: If I use JSONP , will it work for javascript response ? or do I need to return JSON format only?

Comment: JSONP _is_ a JavaScript response - it's just that it (usually) is in the form of a one-line function call passing JSON as a parameter. So yes, it should work if you do it right.